# Draw rectange box with vertical time interval

Tags: pine-script

How to draw rectangle with timeframe interval in pinescript?

Besides that, I have issue construct the vertical line, which sometime the vertical line will be compress all the price's height into smaller, if I define the vertical line. How do make it flexible for vertical line?

#### Vertical Line

```
plot((time == timestamp("GMT-4", 2022,6,30,11,6)) ? 5000 : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 1, title = "End", style = plot.style_histogram)
```

#### Rectangle

[image: Image for Rectange bar on tradingview]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can draw a vertical line at a specific timestamp, without affecting price scaling.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical line at timestamp", overlay=true)

if (barstate.islast)
    x = timestamp(2022,06,7,0,0,0)
    line.new(x, close, x, close * 1.000001, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.green, line.style_dotted)
```

But you could also use `low`/`high`

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical line at timestamp", overlay=true)

if (barstate.islast)
    x = timestamp(2022,06,7,0,0,0)
    line.new(x, low, x, high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.green, line.style_dotted)
```

If you want a rectangle, you can use [box.new()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_box%7Bdot%7Dnew) with `xloc=xloc.bar_time`

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical line and box at timestamp", overlay=true)

if (barstate.islast)
    x1 = timestamp(2022,06,7,0,0,0)
    x2 = timestamp(2022,06,29,0,0,0)
    box.new(x1, low, x2, high, color.green, 0, line.style_dotted, xloc=xloc.bar_time, bgcolor=color.gray)
    line.new(x1, low, x1, high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.green, line.style_dotted)
```

which yields

[image: box with vertical line]

Comment: This is great, thank you. One questions though, how would one create a box like this that displays the highs and lows during a set time frame into the future and the past.